# Use only arabic numbers in book class

Tags: table-of-contents, books

I am writing a book with extbook class.
In the TOC frontmatter uses roman numerals, mainmatter uses arabic numbers.
Publisher asked if I could use only arabic numbers everywhere including in frontmatter.

Is there easy way to do it? If I move preface into mainmatter it adds chapter numbers which is not what I want.

Comment: How do you then distinguish between page 2 of the preface from page 2 of the main matter?  Or do you not restart the page numbering?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess your publisher wants *continuous numbering*: it wouldn't really make sense to have two pages numbered 1, one in the front matter and the other in the main matter.

The definitions in the `book` class are

```
\newcommand\frontmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}%
}
\newcommand\mainmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmattertrue
  \pagenumbering{arabic}%
}
```

so you just have to modify them

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\frontmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{arabic}% <--- changed here
}
\renewcommand\mainmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmattertrue
  %\pagenumbering{arabic}% <--- removed
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `\frontmatter` or `\mainmatter`. These both reset the page numbering which, by default, is arabic.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a best practice or not I used this method:

```
\renewcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  %\@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{arabic}}
```

And after mainmatter (to fix numbering issue in TOC):

```
...
\mainmatter
\cleardoublepage
..
```